# Weird autofill behavior in chrome when using type='Password'

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've run into a weird problem that's definitely related to using type='password' on an input box.

This line works:

`<input id='somePassword' class='blabla' />`

But this line does not:

`<input id='somePassword' class='blabla' type='password' />`

When I use type='password', the browser autofills other unrelated textboxes on the form with random values.  ID fields get the userid from the login page.  Weight fields get a password, etc.  I can make the problem appear and disappear in other input elements just by adding or removing type='password' from this element.

This is of course a password field I'm trying to add.  So I'd like to keep that functionality.

The autocomplete attribute appears to be totally ignored by chrome.

I've tried adding and removing the new input element, adding and removing type='password', and I've tried several autocomplete values.

Initially, Edge showed the same behavior which led to backing out this code.  I haven't tried debugging things on Edge.

Edit:  Doing a $('#somePassword').attr('type', 'password') in document.ready results in the same crazy behavior.

Edit2:  I love how this question keeps getting associated with other posts from people thinking it's already been answered.  Read. The. Question.  This is a bug in chrome.  autofill is broken.  It's autofilling *other* *fields* incorrectly when I add type=password to this one.

Comment: Does this happen even in the very first time you are opening the site in chrome.?
If not, some users prefer autofilling of password which is remembered by the browser. So, this is user preferred  setting which can't be overridden I think.

Comment: You can disable autofill in the browser, then it never does it.  But if you want it on for the login screen, then it sticks crazy values in random input boxes all over the application.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.